# Array of element of the same class javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, dom

How get an array of the values of elements which have same class?

When I do this I get only the first element, but I want a whole array:

```
var classes = document.querySelector(".klass").value;
alert(classes); //Outputs only the first element
```

And I want to get a full array of the values of the inputs:

```
<input type="text" class="klass" />
<input type="text" class="klass" />
<input type="text" class="klass" />
```

Is that possible?

Comment: `var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("klass");` ?

Comment: ... or use `document.querySelectorAll()` instead.

Comment: Seriously guys why the vote down querySelector is a method to use css selectors with JavaScript ?

Comment: Apart from a typo in the post, just reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector) would have made this clear to you ; ).

Comment: @Teemu the hint that you said to me could really help me not the down vote

Comment: Well, the down vote button tooltip says "This question does not show any research effort; ...".

Comment: Downvoting is up to the person, but it is not unreasonable to downvote a question that show a notable lack of research and/or care (such as the spelling of `querySelector`). SO is not a crowd-sourced API documentation service.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) to retrieve a [`NodeList` (see also the section "How can I convert NodeList to Array?")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) then cast it to an array and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) a function that returns each element's value.

```
var classesNodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".klass");
var classes = Array.prototype.slice.call(classesNodeList).map(function(element) {
    return element.value;
});
```

**Update**

---

As stated in the comment by [Ginden](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2446102/ginden), a shorter way to do this is to pass the NodeList to [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) using [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

```
var classesNodeList = document.querySelectorAll(".klass");
var classes = Array.prototype.map.call(classesNodeList, function(element) {
    return element.value;
});
```

Comment: You can even use `[].map.call(nodeList, func)`. ;)

Comment: Yus it's shorter ineed :)

Comment: Can you please simplify how does the function return the value in which form an array or each one in independent variable most of this classes and method are new for me

Comment: @Maroxtn I added links the mdn documentation of each functions and features described above it would be too long to describe it here.

Comment: `Object.setPrototypeOf(NodeList.prototype, Array.prototype); `
 or
`NodeList.prototype.__proto__ = Array.prototype;`

to have all array methods

Answer (score 3):

For such a simple CSS selector expression, I would use [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) and give it the class name, rather than `querySelectorAll`. `getElementsByClassName` is generally faster than using `querySelectorAll` **by several orders of magnitude**. See this [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-v-getelementsbyclassname).

```
var classes = document.getElementsByClassName("klass"); // Do not use a period here!
var values = Array.prototype.map.call(classes, function(el) {
    return el.value;
});
```

`getElementsByClassName` is usually faster than `querySelectorAll`. Browsers index elements by class name already to optimize the speed of CSS transformations. `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection` element, so it does not have the `Array` methods and you need to use `Array.prototype...` on this too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to loop through your array of elements and get the value of each one.

```
var classes = document.querySelectorAll(".klass").value,
    values = [];

for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
    values.push(classes[i].value);
}
```

Note that this may not be as clean as using `[].map`, but is a [good deal faster](http://jsperf.com/loop-vs-map).

Comment: Why do you push classes array into another one or its just a sanity check that everything is fine ?

Comment: You could write over the same array (i.e. `classes[i] = classes[i].value`), but I prefer to avoid doing that because of potential issues/inconsistencies. It will give you essentially the same result, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` method first and then use array's `map` function to retrieve the result:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.klass');
var values = [].map.call(elements, function(e) {
  return e.value;
});
```